# Term Store Management Link is invisible for Group Manager and Contributors

Tags: sharepoint-online, user, term-store, sharepoint-permissions

I want to give a user access to the Term Store Management of a site collection and I noticed that I can add multiple people to the Group Manager field. So I tried it and the user can access this page, but only if he or she specifies the direct URL, which is https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/Websitecollection/_layouts/15/termstoremanager.aspx.

However, when this user opens the website settings, the Term Store Management menu item is not visible... I find it very inappropriate that only the direct link to the Term Store Management can be used.

Is there a user role that can access the Site Collection Term Store anyway? Or how can I include the link in the websitesettings of the websitecollection?

Answer (score 0):

Users need to have at least **Design** permission to see the **Term store management** option under Site Administration.

Adding the user to the Term Store Administrators list gives only the access to the Term Store Management Tool but not the Site Settings of current site.

This is what a user with Design permission can see on the Site settings page (with publishing features deactivated):

[image]

Comment: I think I have the sharepoint server publishing feature activated... what can I do?

Comment: @SharePointNewbie It doesn't matter if the publishing features are activated or not, users still need at least Design permissions to see the option in Site Settings. I was adding the note for one possible layout in Site Settings.

Comment: Okay, all right. Back to the real question. Design is a standard permission level... which specific permission do I need to grant the user?

Comment: @SharePointNewbie Design permission, or Full Control permission if you want the users to have higher privilege.

Comment: Or to put it another way, which checkbox should I check in my custom permission level?

Comment: @SharePointNewbie Per my test, “Apply Themes and Borders” is the permission you need to see the Term store management option under Site settings, and “Manage Lists” is the permission you need to manage terms.